# Is it possible to have delegates that point to the function that have "preset" arguments

Tags: c#, delegates

New to C#. Is it possible to have delegates that point to the function that have "preset" argument that is set by me ?

```
public delegate void Del(string message);
static void Notify(string name)
{
     Console.WriteLine("Notification received for: {0}", name);
}

// Looking for something similar, but code below gives me an error 
// Del del5 = Notify("http://stackoverflow.com");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure - you can have lambda that call that function with whatever arguments you want. In your case us seem to ignore argument altogether which by convention is written as `_` as argument name:

```
Del del5 = _ => Notify("http://stackoverflow.com");  
del5("whatever - ignored anyway"); // always calls Notify("http://stackoverflow.com")
```

More genric case would be to have function with many (i.e.2) parameters and than specify first one to be fixed value in the delegate:

```
static void Notify2(string siteName, string message) {...}
Del messageToStackOverflow = message => 
      Notify2 ("http://stackoverflow.com", message);

// calls Notify2 adding first argument SO: 
// Notify2("http://stackoverflow.com", "Useful message to SO")
messageToStackOverflow("Useful message to SO");
```

In general this called [partial function application](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_application) when you fix some arguments to particular values.

Comment: Алексей, большое спасибо !

Comment: @newprint sure. Side note: not everyone can read Russian. Please try to keep all posts/comment in English as for most readers comments in other languages are not readable and as result unclear if it is praise, curse or request for clarification.

Answer (score 1):

No it is not possible to do it like this, because this would assign the result (void) of the Notify method call to del5. Default parameter values are not allowed for delegates.